# What is the difference between Thresholds and Supported limits in SharePoint 2010 limits?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Searched and found the answer below..

Thresholds: Configurable limits that can be exceeded to accommodate specific requirements
Supported limits: Configurable limits that have been set by default to a tested value

Please explain it with a simple real time example.

Is the limits set by administrators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boundries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Boundaries)

**Boundaries, thresholds and supported limits**

In SharePoint Server 2013, there are certain limits that are by design and cannot be exceeded, and other limits that are set to default values that may be changed by the farm administrator. There are also certain limits that are not represented by a configurable value, such as the number of site collections per web application.

**Boundaries are absolute limits** that cannot be exceeded by design. It is important to understand these limits to ensure that you do not make incorrect assumptions when you design your farm.

An example of a boundary is the 2 GB document size limit; you cannot configure SharePoint Server 2013 to store documents that are larger than 2 GB. This is a built-in absolute value, and cannot be exceeded by design.

**Thresholds** are those that have a default value that cannot be exceeded unless the value is modified. Thresholds can, in certain circumstances, be exceeded to accommodate variances in your farm design, but it is important to understand that doing this may affect the performance of the farm in addition to the effective value of other limits.

The default value of certain thresholds can only be exceeded up to an absolute maximum value. A good example is the document size limit. By default, the default document size threshold is set to 50MB, but can be changed to support the maximum boundary of 2GB.

**Supported limits** define the tested value for a given parameter. The default values for these limits were defined by testing, and represent the known limitations of the product. Exceeding supported limits may cause unexpected results, significant decrease in performance, or other harmful effects.

Some supported limits are configurable parameters that are set by default to the recommended value, while other supported limits relate to parameters that are not represented by a configurable value.

Comment: See if i have 10000 items in list,then how can i get the count?In the link [limit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx) i have found 100 items per bulk operation is only possible

Comment: the threshold limit can be set in powershell and i think in central admin. However it is not advisable because it can degrade the performance of your server. If you want te retrieve many items its better  to use search.

Comment: to get the count you can use list.ItemCount

Comment: Is it possible to get more than 100 items per operation?If it is possible we can use list.ItemCount as you said

Comment: Threshold and Supported limit seem similar, can you explain the difference please?

Answer (score 1):

Threshold is a setting in Central Administration to limit the number of items that a database operation can involve at one time. There is also a setting to alow to overwrite the threshold programmatically. There is also a setting for limit of Lookup, Person/Group or workflow status fields that a database query can involve at one time.
Farm admin can set these values by going to Central Administration -> Manage Application -> Resource throttling

Example: If you have a list with thousands of items, views with high items limit, many lookup columns,... you may need have to change them or change the throttling settings.

Comment: how can we set the default maximum file size as 10 MB in a document library?

Comment: You set the limit per Web Application under Central Admin -> Manage Web Application -> General Settings. I don't know a way to set the limit only for one document library without coding.